# Onlinenic API v4

Tags: php

I am getting authentication error when submitting post request checkDomain Test Server API of onlinenic.
Submitting request on following link
http://ote.onlinenic.com/api4/domain/index.php?command=checkDomain
My form-data values are as follows.

```
user:XXXXX
timestamp:1566289889
token:1df5cdc7a6e68be8d903a299f8515d78
domain:http://testing.com
apikey:XXXXXXXX
password:XXXXXX
```

But not succeeded getting following error.

```
{
    "code": 1006,
    "msg": "Authentication error."
}
```

Comment: @RiggsFolly Im 2k and still can see it :P

Comment: PS: Tried to answer based on those creds, but they give auth error, so not proper ones :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure the method you post data to API, but following example should work.

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://ote.onlinenic.com/api4/domain/index.php?command=checkDomain");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$vars = [
    'user' => 'xxx',
    'timestamp' => '1566289889',
    'token' => 'xxx',
    'domain' => 'testing.com',
    'apikey' => 'xxx',
    'password' => 'xxx',
];
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
          http_build_query($vars));

$server_output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is indicated for wrong token

**token generate**

```
MD5(USERID + MD5(Password) + TimStamp(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10).ToString("yMdHms")) + command(checkDomain)
```

Reference MD5
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.md5?view=netframework-4.8